# Gitlab CICD for laravel app not deploying?

Tags: laravel, gitlab

I am using Gitlab tutorial https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/ for deploying Laravel application to my digital ocean server

But when it’s running task two I am getting following errors.

$ ~/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy run deploy --commit="$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
/bin/bash: line 103: /root/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install envoy in your `before_script` globally in you composer home directory:

```
before_script:
    - export COMPOSER_HOME=`pwd`/composer && mkdir -pv $COMPOSER_HOME
    - composer global require --prefer-dist laravel/envoy=~1.0 --no-interaction --prefer-dist --quiet
```

After this you can call `envoy` in your deploy script like this:

```
- ${COMPOSER_HOME}/vendor/laravel/envoy/envoy run deploy --commit="$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
```

Comment: thank you for helping me. It's working. Now the issues is some permission. you can see on the link. can you please help on this one.
I deploying the code on the shared hosting server. using SSH key.
https://snag.gy/E0UzMc.jpg

Comment: Did you add the SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_GITLAB to the GitLab CI variables as well as the public key to project -> settings -> repository as deploy key? Read more here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/#add-ssh-key. Don't forget to add the public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the server.

Comment: Thank you It's Solved. But I am getting a new error-
https://snag.gy/dHASkI.jpg
Can you please help me on It?

Comment: My server configuration-
OS- Centos7
Web Panel-  Centos wen panel
users- 1- Admin, 2- gitlab
Php Version- 5.6.3
DB- MySql

Answer (score 2):

thank you for the answer i had to add `.../envoy/**bin**/envoy` in the script what worked for me.

complete code : `- ${COMPOSER_HOME}/vendor/laravel/envoy/bin/envoy run deploy --commit="$CI_COMMIT_SHA"`